# What is Non-Intrusive Load Monitoring or energy disaggregation or power signature analysis?

Tags: python, github, dataset, energy

Does anybody know anything about NILM or power signature analysis?

Can i do non-intrusive load monitoring using python?

I got to know about one python toolkit known as NILMTK. But I need help for knowing about NILM.

If anybody know about NILM, then please guide me. Thank you.

Comment: If you want to quickly get started with NILM using Deep Learning, head over to this repository: https://github.com/plexflo/plexflo. We have open sourced a Deep Learning model and have also provided a sample dataset for you to explore NILM.

Answer (score 1):

The aim of non-intrusive load monitoring is to obtain a breakdown of the net energy consumption of a building in terms of individual appliance consumption. There has been work on multiple algorithms so as to get this done ( with varying performance) and as always these can be written in any programming language.

NILMTK itself is written in python and is a good toolkit to describe, analyse and integrate nilm algorithms to compare them.